# Simplifying Python Pandas code for selecting co-occurrences in a window of time

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner at programming. I was able to build the thing below, which achieves what I want with a small dataset. With larger datasets, my RAM gets swamped bringing the computer to a halt (2014 Macbook Pro with 16GB RAM). Can I simplify my process somehow?

```
# This code starts from a co-occurrence list with dates in the first column, like this:
# 
# Jan-20; Monkey; Dog; Horse
# Jan-21; Dog; Horse; Cat
# Jan-22; Monkey; Cat; Dog
# Jan-23; Monkey; Dog; Horse
# 
# That is, these animals occurred together on these specific days.
#
# This code cleans out the list, keeping only those lines that have co-occurrences 
# including an animal below a certain "age" in the dataset. Let's say 2 days. Like this:
#
# Monkey occurred the first time on Jan-20, meaning that lines including 'Monkey' should 
# be kept only if they are dated Jan-# 20 or Jan-21. Cat occurred the first time on Jan-21,
# meaning that lines including 'Cat' should be kept in the dataset only # if they are dated 
# Jan-21 or Jan-22.

# Gather data on dates of earliest occurrence for all included animals
# Set a time window
# Extract lines based on 1 and 2

import pandas

# STEP 1: Gather data on earliest occurence ('entrydates') for all included items

## Set column names
colnames=['Date','Item1','Item2']

## Read csv adding column names
data = pandas.read_csv('/Users/Simon/Dropbox/Work/Datasets/idlehash.csv', names=colnames)

## Create a dataframe with info on dates for first column
datelist1 = data[['Date', 'Item1']]

## Create a dataframe with info on dates for second column
datelist2 = data[['Date', 'Item2']]

## Join the two dataframes into one
entrydates = datelist1.append(datelist2)

## Melt the resulting dataframe into two columns
entrydates = pandas.melt(entrydates, id_vars='Date')[['Date','value']]

## Sort the dataframe by Date and k eep only the earliest occurence of a value
## drop_duplicates considers the column 'value' and keeps only first occurence
entrydates = entrydates.sort('Date').drop_duplicates(cols=['value'])


# STEP 2: Calculate item "ages" in dataset at each co-occurence event

## Create a dataframe with co-occurrence pairs and the entrydates of Item1 in each pair
matrix = pandas.merge(left=data, right=entrydates, left_on='Item1', right_on='value')

## Create a dataframe with co-occurrence pairs and the entrydates of Item2 in each pair
matrix2 = pandas.merge(left=data, right=entrydates, left_on='Item2', right_on='value')

## Rename some of the columns for clarity
matrix = matrix.rename(columns={'Date_x':'co-oc date', 'Date_y':'entrydate of item 1',  
'value':'Item1 (check)'})
matrix2 = matrix2.rename(columns={'Date_x':'co-oc date', 'Date_y':'entrydate of item 2',   
'value':'Item2 (check)'})

## Sort them
matrix = matrix.sort(['co-oc date','entrydate of item 1'], ascending=False)
matrix2 = matrix2.sort(['co-oc date','entrydate of item 2'], ascending=False)

## Join them
gorillaking = pandas.merge(matrix, matrix2, on='Item2', how='outer')

## Build dataframe with selected columns from gorillaking
gorillaking = pandas.concat([gorillaking['co-oc date_x'], gorillaking['Item1_x'],   
gorillaking['Item2'], gorillaking['entrydate of item 1'], gorillaking['entrydate of item 2']],    
axis=1, keys=['date', 'item1', 'item2', 'item1 birth', 'item2 birth'])

## Add a column calculating the "age" of Item 1 on the occasion of each co-occurrence
gorillaking['item1 age'] = gorillaking['date'] - gorillaking['item1 birth']

## Add a column calculating the "age" of Item 2 on the occasion of each co-occurrence
gorillaking['item2 age'] = gorillaking['date'] - gorillaking['item2 birth']


# STEP 3: Select only the co-occurrences that happen in a certain window of time

## Set a timewindow
timewindow = 7

## Extract only the rows where the "age" of Item 1
## is less than or equal to the user defined timewindow
## That is: ('date' - 'item1 birth') <= timewindow
mask = (gorillaking['date'] - gorillaking['item1 birth'] <= timewindow)
keptpairs = gorillaking.loc[mask]

## Output kept pairs to a file
dataset = keptpairs[['item1', 'item2']]
dataset.to_csv('/Users/Simon/Dropbox/Work/Datasets/#keptpairs.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8',    
index=False, header=False)

## Print result
print dataset
```

## EDITED

I finally got the code to achieve what I want, without stressing pandas. I guess this was just as much about realizing what I actually want the code to do. In the above code I calculated the "age" for both Item1 and 2 which was not needed.I finally came up with this code to keep only pairs where the item that comes before the second one has been present in the dataset for less than time T.

```
import pandas

## Set column names
colnames=['Date','Item1','Item2']

## Read csv adding column names
## The csv must be formatted like: 
## date;item1;item2
data = pandas.read_csv('/path/file.csv', names=colnames)

# STEP 1: GET "PUBLICATIONDATES" OF THE TAGS

## Create a dataframe with info 
## on dates for first column
pubdates = data[['Date', 'Item1']]

## Sort the dataframe by Date and 
## keep only the earliest occurence of a value
## drop_duplicates considers the column 'Item1' 
## and keeps only the first occurence
pubdates = pubdates.sort('Date').drop_duplicates(cols=['Item1'])

## Create a dataframe with co-occurrence pairs 
## and the pubdates of Item1 in each pair
timematrix = pandas.merge(left=data, right=pubdates, left_on='Item1', right_on='Item1')

## Rename some of the columns for clarity
timematrix = timematrix.rename(columns={'Date_x':'Coocdate', 'Date_y':'Item1-pubdate',            
'value':'Item1 (check)'})

## Sort them
timematrix = timematrix.sort(['Coocdate','Item1-pubdate'], ascending=False)

## Add a column calculating the "age" 
## of Item 1 on the occasion of each co-occurrence
timematrix['Item1-age'] = timematrix['Coocdate'] - timematrix['Item1-pubdate']

# STEP 2: KEEP ONLY COOCS THAT HAPPEN IN TIME T AFTER ITEM1 PUBDATE

## Set a timeframe
timeframe = 1

## Extract only the rows where the 
## "age" of Item 1 is less than or
## equal to the user defined timeframe
mask = (timematrix['Coocdate'] - timematrix['Item1-pubdate'] <= timeframe)
keptpairs = timematrix.loc[mask]

## Output kept pairs to a file
dataset = keptpairs[['Item1', 'Item2']]
dataset.to_csv('/path/dataset.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Seems more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you give an idea of how big are your datasets?

Comment: The datasets ar at around 250,000 rows

Comment: I see you moved to codereview with this Q, but I have too low rep there. Can you clarify your query a little?
Q1) You wrote
> lines including 'Monkey' should be kept only if they are dated Jan-# 20 or Jan-21.

do you mean you do not consider all _lines_ with 'Monkey' in the line if the line's date > Jan-21 ?
in which case any other Animal's appearance in that lines is skipped.

OR do you mean that you do not consider Monleys in lines later than Jan-21 ?
in which case say if Cat appears 1st time in 'Jan-31 Monkey Cat' it's appearance is taken into account,
and Cat's age is counting from Jan-31.

Comment: it seems you are stressing pandas without any need, but before answering can you explain your goal?

When using your sample data (with dates changed to numbers - like 20000121, etc.) your script gives:
`
     item1   item2
0   Monkey     Dog
1   Monkey     Dog
2   Monkey     Dog
3   Monkey     Dog
4   Monkey     Cat
5      Dog   Horse
[6 rows x 2 columns]` which does not make much sense (to me now).

Comment: @agamike, I edited the code above because I think I finally got it do what I want, without stressing pandas.